# Can a "click of death" from one drive cause an SMI (system management interrupt) or similar?

Tags: hard-drive, clicking-sound

I have two harddrives, and one seems to do the [click of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death#Hard_disk_drives) sometimes (head crash?). At the same time video playback from **another** drive is disturbed (video compression artefacts occur, or video staggers). Why is this?

Comment: It seems my actual problem was that the head was unloaded and then loaded again, just in case someone else is seeking a solution to the same problem. I so far haven't been able to avoid this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.   When a hard drive starts failing the disk subsystems of the PC can be overwhelmed by requests to reread/retry the data, causing a general slowdown.

Comment: I can personally back this up. When dealing with a disk with horrible read errors but not QUITE dead, if it was hooked into my PC's disk controller, the PC wouldn't boot, presumably from the bad reads bogging down the controller. Slapped it on an external USB/SATA adapter with its own controller and I was able to recover the data, albeit after the disk had a spin over the weekend in the freezer.

Comment: Related: [Why is a failing hard disk slow?](http://superuser.com/questions/600165/why-is-a-failing-hard-disk-slow)